# Finding part of the tag with simple html dom

Tags: php, string, search, simple-html-dom

could you please help me.
I'm trying to scrape website while using php simple dome parser from here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Problem is that tags I need to identify have the same beginning, but don't have the same ending. 
For example this is the structure:

```
<div id="postmenu_2861574">
   <div id="post_message_2861574"> one posted message </div>
</div>
<div id="postmenu_2861617">
   <div id="post_message_2861617"> another posted message </div>
</div>
```

All have tags have with the same beginning "post_menu" and "post_message_" but ending differs.
Is it possible to gather all post without knowing all tags endings? 
Is there a way like in sql to use % sign at the end of the search phrase?
As simple way didn't work, showed that variable $postmenu empty.

```
foreach($html->find('div#postmenu_') as $postmenu)
     $item['message'] = $article->find('div#post_message_', 0)->plaintext;
```

thank you for the help

Comment: No you cannot do that... The only aproach so far is what @Petur Olsen suggested... Unless you give the full structure of your DOM, then maybe another way to do it...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i will know for next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html what you are asking is not possible.

I would make all divs with post messages the same class, e.g. class="post_message".

Then you can find all divs with this class using:

```
foreach($html->find('div.post_message') ...
```

Since you are scraping a website, performance is probably not an issue. In this case you can simply find all divs and check the ID, to see if it matches.

```
foreach($html->find('div') ...
  // retreive ID
  if (0 === strpos($id, 'post_message_')))
    ...
```

Comment: thanks, however to change them at first I need to identify them, as there are plenty of unneeded to me div's, and I need again to first find the right tags.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. You are fetching a website and want to scrape it for data. In that case you can see if there is a structure to the data that you can exploit. E.g. in your example you can do find('div div'). This will find all divs nested one level deep. But I'm not sure this will work for the entire document. Alternatively do find('div') and do startsWith($id, "post_message_"). This might be the best in this case.

Comment: Thanks Petur, as you suggested this thing worked "if (0 === strpos($divs->id, 'post_message_'))".